# Creating a fluent interface with multiple terminals and possible invalid intermediate states in C#

Tags: c#, state-machine, fluent

I am trying to create a fluent interface that has two wrinkles;

- It has multiple terminal points
- It has possible invalid intermediate states

I can handle either one of these, but am having trouble with both. Let me give a (slightly simplified) concrete example, assuming that I am extending Stream and the stream is seekable.

I want to support the two flows as follows;

- `stream.GoTo.Offset(x);              // Seek from the beginning`
- `stream.GoTo.Offset(x).From(origin); // Seek from the stated origin, which could be the end`

I therefore could end on an Offset or a From (two terminals). Also, seeking to a point before the start is not allowed. This means if the position was at 10 and the length was 1000, that `stream.GoTo.Offset(-100)` should fail but `stream.GoTo.Offset(-100).From(SeekOrigin.End)` should succeed.

Normally if I have two terminals, I would apply the parts sequentially and all is good; add the Offset to the position first, and at the From, add 0, subtract the original position, or add the length depending on the case. This doesn't work for the problem of the invalid interim state though.

It could well be that there is no solution. I feel like I've simplified it to the point where I can see the options and have eliminated them all. However, I don't write many fluent interfaces and maybe there is at least a work-around I'm not seeing. Any help would be appreciated, even if just to confirm it can't be done.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my previous comment `stream.GoTo.Offset(-100).Go()` `:/`  . `stream.GoTo.Offset(-100,SeekOrigin.End);` `\o/` or func `stream.GoTo(x => x.Offset(x));`

Comment: Yes, I figured. That is disappointing. It doesn't look bad in this simplified case, but it really mucks up the flows that were requested. The plan is for something quite a bit bigger than this. Otherwise, `stream.Goto.Offset(-100, SeekOrigin.End)` is not so far from `stream.Seek(-100, SeekOrigin.End)`.